# "Permission Denied" while uploading an HTTP-posted file from IE to SFTP

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, sftp

Below is my C# code to upload file on ftp, I am using `Renci.SshNet.dll` to connect to sftp.

```
string Address = MyConfigDictionary.GetDictionary["SFTP_Address"].ToString();
int Port = 22;
string UserName = "myusername";
string Password = "mypassword";
string FolderName = "MyFolder";

using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(Address, Port, UserName, Password))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.ChangeDirectory(FolderName + @"/");
    client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
    client.UploadFile(this.GetCmp<FileUploadField>("FileUpload").PostedFile.InputStream, "/" + FolderName + "/" + this.GetCmp<FileUploadField>("FileUpload").PostedFile.FileName, null);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

The code is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but its not working IE.(I am testing in IE 10). I am getting "Permission Denied" in IE.

What am i missing here for IE ?

Comment: You need to specify a full path to upload the file. `client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/home/user/" + f.Name, null);`

Comment: Got the issue: When i am trying with IE, its taking the filename as `C:\Users\user_name\Downloads\myfile.csv` instead of `myfile.csv` why is that ?

Comment: Update the code to where you are getting the file name to this. `Path.GetFileName(uploadedfile)` - change based on your code requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

When trying to upload file using IE, its taking my filename as `C:\Users\user_name\Downloads\myfile.csv` instead of `myfile.csv`

so replaced `this.GetCmp<FileUploadField>("FileUpload").PostedFile.FileName`
with `Path.GetFileName(this.GetCmp<FileUploadField>("FileUpload").PostedFile.FileName)` in `client.UploadFile(..)` above.